# How to get Feature Collection from PostGIS with GeoAlchemy?

Tags: postgis, feature-collection, geoalchemy, flask

I am building a simple Flask app where I want to display all point data stored in PostGIS with Leaflet. What I want to do, is retrieve data in GeoJSON from PostGIS to Flask (using GeoAlchemy) and then pass it to the client.

I tried to use this code:

```
query = db.session.query(geofunc.ST_AsGeoJSON(my_data)).all()
```

It does create correctly formatted data, but it returns each point as a separate GeoJSON object.

```
[('{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type":"Point","coordinates":[-4.259949,55.86592]}, "properties": {"id": 1, "property_2": "some data"}}',), ('{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type":"Point","coordinates":[-4.26158,55.87324]}, "properties": {"id": 2, "property_2": "some data"}}',)]
```

Any idea how I could get the Feature Collection GeoJSON with GeoAlchemy, so it can be easily added to the map?

Comment: The function returns the top-level `features` array - simply concatenate it into a `FeatureCollection` object as per the specs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using the following

```py
import json

myfeatures = [('{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type":"Point","coordinates":[-4.259949,55.86592]}, "properties": {"id": 1, "property_2": "some data"}}',), ('{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type":"Point","coordinates":[-4.26158,55.87324]}, "properties": {"id": 2, "property_2": "some data"}}',)]

print({
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [json.loads(mytuple[0]) for mytuple in myfeatures]
})
```